# SplFileInfo,file_put_contents, and create file

Tags: php, spl

Is there an equivalent to `file_put_contents` with `SplFileInfo`. I see `SplFileInfo::fwrite` but does that account for appending and locking?

Also would about creating a file?

Comment: Not `SplFileInfo`, but `SplFileObject` allows to `fwrite`. And no. there's no `file_put_contents` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `SplFileInfo` has no `fwrite` method. But `SplFileObject` does.
Second - there's no equivalent to `file_put_contents` method both in `SplFileInfo` and `SplFileObject`. But you can extend `SplFileObject` and create it (though I don't know what for).

For example:

```
class MySplFileObject extends SplFileObject {

    public function file_put_contents($contents) 
    {
        $this->fwrite($contents);
    }
}
```